# Printing Last 10000line of a txt into another txt in Unix

Tags: unix, printing, copy, cat, tail

i want to take last 10000 line of a txt file and put it into another file but i get error
here is my code

```
cat | tail - 10000 ihbar_identity.txt > IHBARSONLOG.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or just:

```
tail -10000 ihbar_identity.txt > IHBARSONLOG.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

tail -n 10000 ihbar_identity.txt > IHBARSONLOG.txt